# Intersection not working in apache spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find intersection of two RDD String using apache spark intersection method but it returns empty Array.

```
val d=sc.parallelize(Seq("web services as a software","RCB vs CSK"))

val d1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("software as a services", "CSK vs RCB"))

d.intersection(d1).collect
```

> Output
>
> res6: Array[String] = Array()

Comment: None of your strings are equal. Not really sure what you were expecting to happen

Comment: ? I'm guessing you are looking for intersection of _words_, but your RDDs contain full sentences and indeed none are equal. Maybe you were trying to do `d.flatMap(_.split(" ")).intersection(d1.flatMap(_.split(" "))).collect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the part where you split the sentences into words:

```
val d=sc.parallelize(Seq("web services as a software","RCB vs CSK")).flatMap(_.split(" "))

val d1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("software as a services", "CSK vs RCB")).flatMap(_.split(" "))

d.intersection(d1).collect
```